# Seuda Hoshanah Rabah

Tags: sukkot, sukkah, meal-seudah, weather, hoshana-rabbah

If I recall correctly the reason we eat a Seuda on Hoshanah Rabah is it is the last day we have a Chiuv to eat in the Succah. Suppose it is raining and you can not eat in the Succah do you still have a Chiuv Seuda?

Comment: I've actually never heard of this Seudat Hoshanna Rabba that you speak of. Can you point to a source for it?

Comment: Sefer Hatodaa - Umarbin Bseudas Yom Tov.

Comment: In chutz la'aretz, we arguably have a chiyuv to eat in the Sukkah the day afer hoshanah rabbah also.

Answer (score 3):

It's still Chol Hamoed, so you should probably have a nicer Seudah anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The "Noheg K'Tzon Yosef" (pg. 298) cited in Nitey Gavriel (Hilchos Sukkos pg. 383) explains the reason for the minhag of eating a seudah on Hoshana Rabba to demonstrate our confidence in a victorious outcome of the judgment. Accordingly, the seuda should be held irrespective of whether it is in the Sukkah or not.