# Meal on Hoshanah Rabbah

Tags: halacha, meal-seudah, hoshana-rabbah

People tell me there's an idea to have a big meal on Hoshanah Rabbah. I don't see this anywhere in Shulchan Aruch (668), Rema, or Mishnah Berurah. I see the Magen Avraham there says that people who have a Hoshanah Rabbah seudah after Mincha are behaving inappropriately, since it's Erev Chag. Is that to imply before Mincha is proper? Or he doesn't necessary feel it's necessary, just not an issue like after Mincha is. Aruch HaShulchan (249:7) also talks about how people eat a huge meal on Hoshanah Rabbah and he feels it's inappropriate as it's Erev Chag. What about a small meal? Does he condone that?

Are there any halachic sources which suggest eating a meal? [This site](https://din.org.il/2020/10/07/%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%90-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94/) cites Menoras HaMaor but as far as I know that's a Mussar/Kabbalah sefer.

Comment: If you say leisheiv basukkah in the afternoon, you can start Yom Tov and make kiddush early without running into the Maharil's issue :)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3095/seuda-hoshanah-rabah

Comment: @GershonGold yeah that article also cited this "Noheg K'Tzon Yosef", but I don't know who that is.

Comment: @robev speaking without context, the most famous work IME with that title is https://hebrewbooks.org/14576